# VSCode: how to undo split screen and show just current file?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

VSCode provides sweet shortcuts for manipulating (splitting and rearranging) screens:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd> to split your screen in two.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Number</kbd> to focus on one of the screeens
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> to change vertical/horizontal split

However, how do I remove all the split screens and just show the currently focused one?

**Example:** say, I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd> two times (gives me three vertical screens), then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> to select middle screen. What should I press now to make left and right screen disappear and middle screen occupy the whole space? In Emacs, that would be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>.

Comment: I guess without a shortcut then since each split window has its own x, one could just close it with a click!

Comment: But it's not a "sweet" feature. Throwing in this thread: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/71016

Comment: Not sure if I understood the issue correctly, but if you a) use file tabs and b) move those file tabs around with a mouse, then you're doing two things wrong at the same time. You should a) not use tabs and b) use a shortcut + fuzzy search to jump to the file you want. Not a user of VSCode anymore, I am still happy with my emacs.

Comment: How do we stop it happening altogether? I'm just dragging a file in and it's splitting the screen... I don't even want the feature at all

Comment: The x by each window closes it?  Who knew.  I thought it would close the whole file.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

See if this keybinding does what you want:

```
{
  "key": "alt+q",
  "command": "workbench.action.closeEditorsInOtherGroups"
}
```

There is no default keybinding for the command `workbench.action.closeEditorsInOtherGroups` so I made up that one.  I think it accomplishes what you want.  It will close the other editor groups and keep you at the focused group.

Alternatively you can set a shortcut such as:

```
{
  "key": "alt+q",
  "command": "workbench.action.joinAllGroups"
}
```

This merges all open Groups into one window instead of closing all the unfocused ones.

Both shortcuts can also be set in the GUI by "Ctrl + Shift + P" -> Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts.

Comment: `closeEditorsInOtherGroups` is exactly the action I was looking for, thanks a lot!

Comment: A problem with this is that it results in prompts asking whether you want to save the file. But I believe what this question is looking for is a purely view-level operation: remove the split and display one file only. That operation should not result in any questions regarding the state of the file on disk.

Comment: Agreed.  What it turned out I wanted when I came upon this answer was `Join all editor groups`.

Comment: I think @rswerve's command should be put in an answer because it's more appropriate.

Answer (score 67):

I solved this by clicking on *View* > *Editor Layout* > *Single*.

[image]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, it works great and doesn't close any of the files in either group.

Comment: They need to add something next to the split icon to do this, it's just a bit too hidden.

Answer (score 5):

Invoke Command palette (pressing `Ctrl + Shift + P` by default) and type/search for:

`View: Close Editors in Other Groups`

Answer (score 3):

Click and drag up between CRLF and the up arrow, it allows you to close the window with your mouse only

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Hello, you should include your image in your post directly instead of linking it. Some structure in your post would also be good. I recommend looking at top answers and some tutorials before you write your answer. Remember that you can look at the preview before posting. Feel free to edit already posted answers. The fact that you are a new user is irrelevant. Hope this will help you move forward.

Comment: It won't let me add an image directly, do you have other tips on how to get a screenshot in? I spent like 30 minutes trying to add it but it told me I needed a certain number of "points" before I could add in images.

Comment: Sorry emb, I forgot that you couldn't add images directly as a new user. My bad. 
I guess that you did the best possible with the image. You can do more cool stuff like adding images when you gain more reputation. 
Here is a link explaining it better: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

Comment: Intuitive! This doesn't work for left/right splits, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

View Menu -> Editor Layout -> Single

Answer (score 2):

For mac: cmd + alt + 1

For windows:

1. ctrl + k, ctrl + s open keyboard short cut
2. Search "view single", find "View: Single Column Editor Layout" which is empty.
3. Double click to add a shortcut(Say ctrl + alt + 1), then click enter.
4. Now you have your own shortcut.

Comment: There isn't an "alt" key on Mac.

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer. I asked for this in a feature request on GitHub and came back here and found out that they basically told me to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to right-click on any tab in the split group you don't want and choose "Close All". It also shows the keyboard shortcut (Ctrl+K W by default), which you can remap:

[image: close split window]